# Eclipse dynamic web project / build folder / compilation

Tags: eclipse, spring

I am doing my dynamic web project using Spring framework and Eclipse as IDE. I noticed that class folder under this project is always empty .
My questions are :

**1 )** If I have 'build automatically' option checked ,does it mean that it's continuous building ? Why build folder is empty ?

**2 )** What happened to project files when I click 'run on server' . Does Eclipse copy those file to Tomcat required structure and run ?

*When I was doing some servlet for learning I had to copy files under specified project tree in Tomcat and run it from console so , I am interested how it works under eclipse*

**3)** If I have some classes and I just want to compile it to see log errors how to achieve that ? Whenever I do 'build' there is no logs in console output in eclipse.

Comment: Noticed it where? You're shown source files since that's what you'll be modifying, the corresponding class files are usually hidden from view. And build automatically just means you're either building right then or are already fully built.

Answer (score 1):

1) No, but it's done automatically when you save(not an external build like an Ant build, but the "internal" build). If you don't want to build on save, you'd uncheck the box. Having it build automatically makes some people nervous, I believe.

Sorry got no idea 'bout the others :P